# What is the earliest reference of three truths doctrines found among Advaitin's literature?

Tags: advaita, reference-request

As of today, almost all Advaita VedAntins espousing [three truths theory](http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/definitions/paramartha2.htm) using below terms

- prAtibhAsika satya
- vyAvahArika satya (Relative truth)
- pAramArthika satya (Absolute reality)

Does any Adi Sankara's work talk about these three truths? If not, What is the earliest Advaita VedAntin's work found to use the three truth doctrines and using what Sanskrit terms?

Also, As a side note, [Two truths doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_truths_doctrine) (corresponds to so-called relative and absolute truth) is found in Buddhism - a reference before Adi Sanakara. In Nāgārjuna's Mūlamadhyamakakārikā the two truths doctrine is used to defend the identification of dependent origination (pratītyasamutpāda) with emptiness (śūnyatā):

> The Buddha's teaching of the Dharma is based on two truths: a truth of
>   worldly convention and an ultimate truth. Those who do not understand
>   the distinction drawn between these two truths do not understand the
>   Buddha's profound truth. Without a foundation in the conventional
>   truth the significance of the ultimate cannot be taught. Without
>   understanding the significance of the ultimate, liberation is not
>   achieved

Comment: you have multiple questions. you are asking for a reference from adi shankara and a advaita reference from before Nagarjuna. questions should be limited to one per posting. please edit your question into 2 questions.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda My question is pretty clear. I am basically asking what Advaitin's work talks about two truth doctrines as usually propounded nowadays (relative and absolute truth). If Adi Sankara himself talked about then he also can be quoted. Nagarjuna thing or second paragraph, which starts with 'As a side note', is redundant. It isn't part of the question itself.